# Speed up read/write of xlsx files in R

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I am over-writing existing tabs in an excel workbook (.xlsx). I want to preserve the order of the tabs/sheets in the workbook and I also have multiple headers so I am overwriting the sheets at certain rows (one line of code for the header/one for the data) using openxlsx. However the process is very slow. I tried using the xlsx library however nothing I do can prevent Java memory errors from appearing. Does anyone know of a way to speed up this proccess or another library to try?

```
gc()

# load file contents
filename <- list.files()[grep("DATA_SF",list.files())]

wb<- openxlsx::loadWorkbook(filename)
openxlsx::writeData(wb, "Question_Text", as.data.frame(Question_Text), startRow = 1, startCol = 1)

openxlsx::writeData(wb, "Raw Data (Split)", as.data.frame(split_qualtricsheaders), startRow = 1, startCol = 1, colNames = F)
openxlsx::writeData(wb, "Raw Data (Non-split)", as.data.frame(nonsplit_qualitricsheaders), startRow = 1, startCol = 1, colNames = F)

openxlsx::writeData(wb, "Raw Data (Split)", as.data.frame(split_qualtrics), startRow = 3, startCol = 1, colNames = F)
openxlsx::writeData(wb, "Raw Data (Non-split)", as.data.frame(nonsplit_qualitrics), startRow = 3, startCol = 1, colNames = F)

openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wb,file = filename, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: There are several other packages - `writexl` is supposed to be quite fast, though I think it is less fully featured than `openxlsx`.

Comment: @GregorThomas I saw this yeah but how would I get around writing 2 headers and preserving the existing tabs?

Comment: If the whole process is slow, it‘s likely due to the size of your Excel file. But it‘s impossible to know unless you share some detail about it (file size, number of sheets…).

Comment: unfortunately the sizes and sheets are always different.